# How to use UIWebView access domain with specified IP

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

```
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL 
URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
```

For example,google.com has a lot of servers.But some ip address can't be connected.

If I access the google.com with the specify the ip(74.125.128.99),the connected is ok.

How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question - could you please be more specific? The above code should work with no problems.

Comment: This isn't answer but a comment.

Comment: It is the same as using the hosts file with the linux.